# Rails: Can't use member outside resource(s) scope (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been upgrading to Rails 4, and after running command "rspec ." I am getting the following error:

```
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1297:in `member': can't use member outside resource(s) scope (ArgumentError)
```

I have changed my route file a little and still no work. If anyone has run into a similar issue and has a fix please share with me. Thanks in advance!

```
Dating::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  get 'edit' => 'users#edit'
  get "/profile/:id" => "users#show"
  get "profile/:id/settings" => 'users#edit'
  get 'settings/:id' => 'users#settings'

  resources :sessions
  resources :password_resets
  resources :galleries
  resources :photos
  resources :searches

  resources :questions do
    resources :answers, only: [:new, :create]
  end

  resources :users do  
    member do
      get :settings
  end
end

  root to: 'galleries#index'

  resources :users do |user|
    resources :messages do
      collection do
        post 'delete_multiple'
         get 'settings', on: :member  
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: This is your all your routes code?

Comment: Yes that's the full code minus a extra "end" that is at the bottom of the file that follows the hashtags for documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
resources :messages do
  collection do
    post 'delete_multiple'
     get 'settings', on: :member  # <--here
  end
end
```

You can't define a member inside the collection, you should move it up to the resources block, like this:

```
resources :messages do
  collection do
    post 'delete_multiple'
  end
  get 'settings', on: :member
end
```

Remember that a member route will require an ID, because it acts on a member. A collection route doesn't because it acts on a collection of objects.
So you can't use both at the same time.